# Bayesian Inference: Updating Under Uncertainty

Tags: bayesian, bayes-theorem

Bayes Theorem:
$$Pr(A|B) = \frac{Pr(A)*Pr(B|A)}{Pr(B)} \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,(0)$$

Furthermore:
$$Pr(A) = Pr(A|B)*Pr(B) + Pr(A|\neg B)*Pr(|\neg B) \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,(1)$$

**Scenario:**
Suppose we are not given that an event $B$ has occured.
Assuming we are given a base Probability of $A$:  $(Pr(A_1)$ (this is our prior probability), subsequently, we are now given a $Pr(A|B_1)$, a $Pr(B_1)$, a $Pr(A|\neg B_1)$, and a $Pr(\neg B_1)$ as additional information. Assuming, that I now want to calculate a $Pr(A_2)$ that is the posterior probability in light of the new information.

From $(1)$:
$$Pr(A_2) = Pr(A|B_1)\cdot Pr(B_1) + Pr(A|\neg B_1)\cdot Pr(\neg B_1)\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,(2)$$

From $(0)$:
$Pr(A|B_1) = \frac{Pr(A_1)*Pr(B_1|A)}{Pr(B_1)} \,\,:\,\, Pr(A|\neg B_1) = \frac{Pr(A_1)*Pr(\neg B_1|A)}{Pr(\neg B_1)} \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,(3)$$

Rewriting $(2)$ in light of $(3)$
$$Pr(A_2) = \frac{Pr(A_1)*Pr(B_1|A)}{Pr(B_1)} \times Pr(B_1) + \frac{Pr(A_1)*Pr(\neg B_1|A)}{Pr(\neg B_1)} \times Pr(\neg B_1)$$

Which gives us:
$$Pr(A_2) = Pr(A_1)*Pr(B_1|A) + Pr(A_1)*Pr(\neg B_1|A)$$
Simplifying to:
$$Pr(A_2) = Pr(A_1)\cdot\left(Pr(B_1|A) +Pr(\neg B_1|A)\right)\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,(4)$$

Generalising from $(4)$:
$$Pr(A_{l+1}) = Pr(A_l)\cdot\left(Pr(B_l|A) +Pr(\neg B_l|A)\right)\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,(5)$$

**My Question:**

1. Is $(5)$ valid bayesian inference?
2. If not, how do I perform valid
   inference in the specified scenario?